# What is the easiest way to install ubuntu

Tags: wubi, downloads

I have a desktop 32bit Windows computer in which i am trying to install ubuntu. I haven't used this computer in years! The software is a little outdated and i was trying to fully turn it into an ubuntu machine.

Does anyone know whats the easiest way to do this? I tried downloading a disk image and using wubi but it didn't work maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: Standard Ubuntu needs a fairly new processor and graphics chip to work well. An old computer will work better with one of the Ubuntu family flavours with a light desktop environment. Try the ultra-light Lubuntu and the medium light Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu. Please stay away from wubi. See the following links and links from them, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640

Comment: @ddbug maybe slightly funny but not really helpful...

Answer (score 1):

1. Download an .iso file of Ubuntu from the official website.
2. Burn it onto a DVD. (DO NOT COPY AND PASTE AS THIS WON'T WORK)
3. Restart your computer and go to BIOS settings (usually done by pressing F12 while the system is rebooting)
4. Choose to boot from disk
5. Select *Install Ubuntu*